# HTML live video feed hosted through flask is not visible on other devices

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, streaming

My friend and I are working on building a small rover to drive around for fun. We are going about it by creating a website that would be hosted on a Raspberry Pi so that only people connected to the same wifi would be able to view it (By typing in the pi's IP and the port into a web browser). Right now, I am working on hosting the website using flask. My code is working, and when I open up the flask app on the pi I can see the video feed coming from my webcam, but when I access the site on another device I see the plain gray box that I created for the video to be placed in (without the feed). Side note: We tried MJPEG streamer and it worked, but I want to be able to put buttons and controls for the rover on the page as well. Here is my python code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True, host = "0.0.0.0", port = 80)
```

Here is the HTML code (index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Le Rover</title>

<style>
#container {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 375px;
    border: 10px #333 solid;
}
#videoElement {
    width: 500px;
    height: 375px;
    background-color: #666;
}
#title {
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 id="title">Mason and Keith's Rover</h1>
<div id="container">
    <video autoplay="true" id="videoElement">

    </video>
</div>
<script>
var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");

if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
    .then(function (stream) {
      video.srcObject = stream;
    })
    .catch(function (err0r) {
      console.log("Something went wrong!");
    });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The HTML, CSS, and Javascript above I got from a live streaming tutorial, so I do not fully understand how it works. I am not sure if it is something with the Javascript or something with my python flask code. If you have a solution, please respond.

Comment: Which device works and which doesn’t? You can open your web browser developer windows and see what errors it throws. I discovered in my project that JavaScript syntax is different from Web browsers and iOS devices!

Comment: It only works on my raspberry pi (the hosting device). I tried it on my phone and laptop and the feed would not appear. I’ll check the errors.